# Pandas library unable to read csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have just one line of code which reads a CSV file into a variable df, but this gives the following error: No columns to parse from file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("D:\Folder1\train.csv")
```

The CSV file is at this location (I've checked it more than once) and the CSV file was being correctly read until I updated the pandas library.
Can someone tell me how to remove this error?

Comment: Can you add an example of your csv?

Comment: Try using forward slashes `"/"` in your path or pass a raw string: `df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Folder1\train.csv")` your backslash is escaping on `'\f'` and `'\t'` making it a form feed and tab character respectively

Comment: And please don't use raw string paths in code. Try something OS agnostic, like [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica It still gives the same error after replacing backslashes with forward slashes.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar What kind of an example do you want (A screenshot of the file or something else)?

Comment: So then your csv isn't where you think it is, or you csv is malformed, post a link to the raw csv file

Comment: @Alottadoubts  a file

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. The original file was modified and hence I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use forward slashes "/" in your path